# List the first 20 friendly number pairs

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, number-theory

I just started reading about [friendly numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number) and I think they sound great.

> In number theory, **friendly numbers** are two or more natural numbers with a common **abundancy**, the ratio between the sum of divisors of a number and the number itself. Two numbers with the same abundancy form a **friendly pair**; *n* numbers with the same abundancy form a **friendly *n*-tuple**.

So, how small  a program can you write to output a list of the first 20 friendly numbers.

Assuming I've understood everything I've read correctly the output of your program should be:

```
6,28
30,140
80,200
40,224
12,234
84,270
66,308
78,364
102,476
6,496
28,496
114,532
240,600
138,644
120,672
150,700
174,812
135,819
186,868
864,936
222,1036
246,1148
```

I'd also like to add that the program must calculate the answers and not use any external resources or hard coded answers (thanks Peter).

Comment: can you quote the definition here? We StackExchangers don't like having to visit external sites :-)

Comment: Two things. Firstly, you ask for the *first* items but you haven't defined a total ordering on them. Secondly, you make the common beginner's error of not taking requiring the program to do the calculation. I strongly advise you to edit the question to prohibit the use of external resources (or someone will submit a program which downloads the answer) and to require the program to input `N` and output the first `N` such pairs (or someone will submit an answer which just uncompresses a precomputed literal string).

Comment: In addition to @PeterTaylor's remarks - in case you consider `N` being variable you'd have to specify how n-tuples with n>2 should be handled.

Comment: +1 to @PeterTaylor. Aside from prohibiting external resources, you also need to forbid hard-coding of the numbers.

Comment: I think you missed `6,496` and `28,496` in your list.

Comment: Thanks Marinus, I've added those in - I'll update my program to fix it too.

Comment: It may go without saying, but you should specify *known* friendly numbers.  There are many small numbers (including 10) which have no known friends but which are not known for certain to be solitary.

Comment: @MarkReed That's arguably contradictory. Specifying the output only needs to include *known* friendly numbers may lead to hard-coded limitations which would not truly have the program calculate friendly numbers on its own. However, it is also worth noting that the only way to prove a number is *solitary* (without hard-coding it) would be to exhaustively search infinity to determine that it indeed has no friends - something which is obviously impractical.

Comment: @lszi I only meant that we can't definitively say that the output is "the first N friendly numbers" since some other number may displace one of the N via discovery of a friend. I did not mean to imply any logical changes to the code, on the wording of the problem.  Also, there are ways to prove solitude without exhaustion, but they're involved and generally quite specific to the number whose solitude is in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### APL (50)

```
↑⊃,/{g/⍨{=/{⍵÷⍨+/z/⍨0=⍵|⍨z←⍳⍵}¨⍵}¨g←⍵∘.,⍳⍵-1}¨⍳936
```

The list is slightly different but [oeis.org](http://oeis.org/A050972) [agrees with me.](http://oeis.org/A050973)

Output:

```
 28   6
140  30
200  80
224  40
234  12
270  84
308  66
364  78
476 102
496   6
496  28
532 114
600 240
644 138
672 120
700 150
812 174
819 135
868 186
936 864
```

Answer (score 5):

## C (132)

```
x=1,e;float d(a,b){return b?1.f*(a%b==0)*b/a+d(a,--b):0;}main(){while(x<1148)for(e=x++;--e;)d(x,x)-d(e,e)||(printf("%d,%d\n",e,x));}
```

Thanks to shiona for the ideas on shorter code.
And Felix Eve for the Code(counting down makes more sense if you only search pairs).
With the added Pairs even shorter.

Readable Version:

```
x=1,e;

float d(a,b)
{
    return b?1.f*(a%b==0)*b/a+d(a,--b):0;
}


main()
{
    while(x<1148)
        for(e=x++;--e;)
            d(x,x)-d(e,e)||(printf("%d,%d\n",e,x));
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of improvements to this. I'll make some edits and put them to a pastebin or something and link here.

Comment: Yes I am Pretty sure, that this can be less than the hard coded Results and I found a few Bytes to optimize out.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AVX6KNau It's by no means perfect, but I hope it'll help you make messier C code :D

Comment: Yes, I have to try my new C skills at work, I think my code looks too clean :P

Comment: No need to include header file. It will compile without header file(with warnings about impicit declaration of built in functions).You can also just declare `main()` instead of `int main()`.Perhaps you may try this trick too ;) `main(x,e,f){x=1;f=21;`

Comment: Since you couldn't get the default int & no headers trick working, I'm wondering. Is your file .c or .cc (or .cpp). gcc tries to be clever and compiles the two latter as c++. The file I provided does compile for me with gcc 4.8.2 when saved with .c extension.

Comment: You are right it actually does compile I thought the warning was an error.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 90 characters

```
h={}
1.upto(1150){|n|s=0
1.upto(n){|x|s+=x if n%x<1}
r=s/n.to_r
p [h[r],n] if h[r]
h[r]=n}
```

Comment: Nice, although it doesn't include the line [6, 496], here are the results: http://ideone.com/HrLpbr

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica <s>114 112 99</s>  90

**Numbers having same abundancy.** (90 chars)

This  displays integers with a common abundancy. Notice that 6, 28, and 496 have the same abundancy, which means that (6,28), (6,496) and (28, 496) are friendly number pairs. Likewise, 84, 270, 1488, 1638 have the same abundancy.

Because, as Peter Taylor noted, there is no method suggested for total ordering, it is unclear which pairs constitute the "first 20" friendly number pairs.

```
Grid@Cases[GatherBy[{k, 1~DivisorSigma~k/k}~Table~{k, 2000}, Last], x_ /; Length@x > 1 
:> x[[All, 1]]]
```

[image: abundancy]

Comment: I  used the term `abundancY` because otherwise the auto-spelling checker coverts the word to `abundance`.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica <s>62</s> <s>58</s> 55

```
Grid@Cases[GatherBy[Range[6!],Tr@Divisors@#/#&],{_,__}]

6   28  496
12  234 
30  140 
40  224 
66  308 
78  364 
80  200 
84  270 
102 476 
114 532 
120 672 
138 644 
150 700 
240 600
```

You may go up to `9!` without affecting the char count

Answer (score 1):

Using awk (303, uncompressed)

```
 awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=1150;i++)
             { for (j=1;j<=int(i/2);j++)
                  if (i%j=="0") a[i]+=j
                v=sprintf("%.10f",(a[i]+i)/i)
                #print v,i
               b[v]=b[v] FS i
              }
           for (i in b) {l=split(b[i],x,FS);if (l>1) print b[i]}}' file|sort -n

 6 28 496
 12 234
 30 140
 40 224
 66 308
 78 364
 80 200
 84 270
 102 476
 114 532
 120 672
 135 819
 138 644
 150 700
 174 812
 186 868
 222 1036
 240 600
 246 1148
 864 936
```

Answer (score 0):

### C - 188

I assume someone will do this with a language that supports literal newlines and requires less boilerplate.

```
main(){puts("6,28\n30,140\n80,200\n40,224\n12,234\n84,270\n66,308\n78,364\n102,476\n114,532\n240,600\n138,644\n120,672\n150,700\n174,812\n135,819\n186,868\n864,936\n222,1036\n246,1148");}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - 260

```
$x=1;while($i<20){$d=0;$y=$x;for($y=$x;$y>0;$y--){if($x%$y==0)$d+=$y;}$f=$d/$x.'';$s[$f][]=$x;if(count($s[$f])>1) {$i++;if(count($s[$f])>2){$o[]=$s[$f][0].','.$s[$f][2];$o[]=$s[$f][1].','.$s[$f][2];}else $o[]=implode(',',$s[$f]);}$x++;}echo implode('<br>',$o);
```

Uncompressed:

```
$x=1;
$o = array();
while($i<20) {
    $d = 0;
    $y = $x;
    for($y=$x;$y>0;$y--) {
        if($x%$y==0) $d += $y;
    }
    $f = $d / $x.' ';
    $s[$f][] = $x;
    if(count($s[$f])>1) {
        $i++;
        if(count($s[$f])>2) {
            $o[] = $s[$f][0].','.$s[$f][2];
            $o[] = $s[$f][1].','.$s[$f][2];
        } else {
            $o[] = implode(',', $s[$f]);    
        }
    }
    $x++;
}
echo implode('<br>', $o);
```

This answer is longer than my other answer but works properly (doesn't skip any numbers and only has 2 numbers per row) so I'm more happy with this one.

Answer (score 0):

C#: 208

```
public class A{static double D(int n){return 1f*Enumerable.Range(1,n).Where(i=>n%i==0).Sum()/n;}static void Main(){for(int j,i=1;i++<865;)for(j=1;j++<1000;)if(A.D(i)==A.D(j)&&i<j)Console.WriteLine(i+" "+j);}}
```